# Git submodule ignore error at branch checkout when that submodule does not have that branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules, git-checkout

I have 6 sub modules in a git repository, says submodule1, submodule2,... submodule6.
On 4 sub modules: submodule1/2/4/5 I have a branch, says featureABC, on them.

When I run the checkout command:

```
$ git submodule foreach git checkout featureABC
```

there is an errror:

```
error: pathspec 'featureABC' did not match any file(s) known to git
fatal: run_command returned non-zero status for submodule3
```

I know that submodule3/6 do not have branch featureABC and I want to ignore them when run recursive checkout. So my question is: is there any way to ignore checkout error, leave the branch of submodule3/5 as it is and continue to other submodule checkout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore all errors with this shell syntax:

```
git submodule foreach "git checkout featureABC || :"
```

`:` means "do nothing".

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you very much! BTW, is there any way we can drop the quote? I'm trying to make an alias for this on linux shell, e.g. `alias gis='git submodule foreach git'`

Comment: @QuocNg "*…is there any way we can drop the quote?*" No, the entire subcommand must be passed to a shell as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way we can drop the quote?
> I'm trying to make an alias for this on linux shell, e.g. `alias gis='git submodule foreach git'`

You would need a git alias with parameters:

```
alias git = '!f() { git submodule foreach "git switch ${1} || :"; }'
```

I am using here [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) ([Git 2.23, Q3 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)) instead of `git checkout`. `git switch` works only with branches, not "branches or files" like `git checkout`.